# PHP delete functionality probably logical error

Tags: php, html, mysql, content-management-system

In the top of my admin PHP (admin.php), I have loaded data from "Sport" table in "DogSport" MySQL database. After clicking "Edit" link of a particular record, I can 
edit, delete that record on "editform2.php". Even on that page, I can also insert a new record.

[image]

Problem: Deleting first and second records do not work! Deleting all following records work fine. This problem only with deleting functionality.

Code segment - admin.php

```
<?php
                        include("dbconnect.inc.php");
                        //Retrieving Data
                        $query1="SELECT * FROM Sport ORDER BY SportId ASC";
                        $result2=mysqli_query($con, $query1);
                        $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
                        $i=0;           
                        if($rows==0)
                            echo "<br/>There are no records";
                        else{
                            echo "<table id='sport'>";
                            echo "<tr><th>Sport Id</th><th>Sport Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>";

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                            {
                                echo "<tr><td>" . $row["SportId"] . "</td><td>" . $row["SportName"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Description"] .
                                "</td><td> <a href='editform2.php?id=" . $row["SportId"] . "' target='_blank'>Edit</a></td></tr>";

                                $i++;
                            }
                            echo "</table>";
                        }
                    ?>
```

Code segment - editform2.php

```
if(isset($_POST["delete"])){
include("dbconnect.inc.php");
$query3="DELETE FROM Sport WHERE SportId=$id";
mysqli_query($con, $query3);
echo "<h1>Deleted Successfully</h1>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

}

I have uploaded necessary files, you can also use to check it including database .sql script. Your help is appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wn40u93oa1sxcph/SO.rar?dl=0

Comment: Not sure if 100% but you are using mysqli_query($con, $query3) and based on your dropbox files, $con only selected the database server, not the database itself? Should it be mysqli_query($db_selected, $query3) or change $con in your dbconnect.inc.php file to mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) and eliminate that extra step of connecting to the database seperately

Comment: your suggestion seems correct! I will try it soon. But mysterious thing is that deleting does not work only for the first two records. The following records are deleted without any problem. If there is a problem selecting database, none of records delete. :(

Comment: I have uploaded all this to my server and I am able to delete all the rows. Can you confirm what the problem is?

Comment: Problem is very strange. "Sport" table has 5 records. If I try to delete the first or second record (for example, sport id 1 and 2) it shows that they are deleted (no error shown) but they have actually not been deleted from the database table. But strange thing is that if I delete the records (sport id 3, 4, 5) they are actually deleted from the table. Problem exists only with the first and second records when deleting only. They are actually updated also..

Comment: I downloaded your files, uploaded them, added the SQL tables to a test database and when I deleted those rows through the editform page, everything from the `Sport` table we removed. As expected. Perhaps something is reinserting them on your end after they are being removed? Although, with the data you gave in dropbox, everything works fine.

Comment: It is really surprise. I check again carefully and let you know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$query3="DELETE FROM Sport WHERE SportId=$id";
```

Where did you set value of $id? It should be `$_POST["id"]` right?

As a side note - SQL injection risk ...

Comment: when i click "Edit" link of a particular record, $id is sent from admin.php to editform2.php via URL. In editform2.php there is a button to delete that record. isset($_POST["delete"]) checks if the user has clicked that button.